# cuda shared library linking: undefined reference to cudaRegisterLinkedBinary

Tags: c++, cuda, makefile, shared-libraries, nvcc

Goal:

1. create a shared library containing my CUDA kernels that has a CUDA-free wrapper/header.
2. create a `test` executable for the shared library.

Problem

1. shared library `MYLIB.so` seems to compile fine. (no problem).
2. Error in linking:

`./libMYLIB.so: undefined reference to __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_000018cf_00000000_6_MYLIB_cpp1_ii_74c599a1`

simplified makefile:

```
libMYlib.so :  MYLIB.o
    g++  -shared  -Wl,-soname,libMYLIB.so  -o libMYLIB.so    MYLIB.o  -L/the/cuda/lib/dir  -lcudart


MYLIB.o : MYLIB.cu   MYLIB.h
    nvcc  -m64   -arch=sm_20 -dc  -Xcompiler '-fPIC'  MYLIB.cu  -o  MYLIB.o  -L/the/cuda/lib/dir  -lcudart


test : test.cpp  libMYlib.so
        g++   test.cpp  -o test  -L.  -ldl -Wl,-rpath,.   -lMYLIB  -L/the/cuda/lib/dir  -lcudart
```

---

indeed

`nm  libMYLIB.so`  shows that **all** CUDA api functions are "undefined symbols":

```
         U __cudaRegisterFunction
         U __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_0000598c_00000000_6_CUPA_cpp1_ii_74c599a1
         U cudaEventRecord
         U cudaFree
         U cudaGetDevice
         U cudaGetDeviceProperties
         U cudaGetErrorString
         U cudaLaunch
         U cudaMalloc
         U cudaMemcpy
```

So CUDA somehow did not get linked to the shared library  MYLIB.so
What am I missing?

---

CUDA did not even get linked to the object file somehow:

`nm  MYLIB.o`

```
         U __cudaRegisterFunction
         U __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_0000598c_00000000_6_CUPA_cpp1_ii_74c599a1
         U cudaEventRecord
         U cudaFree
         U cudaGetDevice
         U cudaGetDeviceProperties
         U cudaGetErrorString
         U cudaLaunch
         U cudaMalloc
         U cudaMemcpy
```

(same as above)

Comment: There is no static version of the cuda runtime library so you shouldn't ever expect to see runtime library symbols statically included in either the object or your shared library, so your last two edits/additions are red herrings here.

Comment: Ah ok, I did not know that, good point.

Comment: @talonmies actually beginning with CUDA Toolkit 5.5 there is also a static version of the CUDA Runtime library

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example linux shared object creation along the lines you indicated:

1. create a shared library containing my CUDA kernels that has a
   CUDA-free wrapper/header.
2. create a test executable for the shared library.

First the shared library.  The build commands for this are as follows:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -Xcompiler '-fPIC' -dc test1.cu test2.cu
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -Xcompiler '-fPIC' -dlink test1.o test2.o -o link.o
g++ -shared -o test.so test1.o test2.o link.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
```

It seems you may be missing the second step above in your makefile, but I haven't analyzed if there are any other issues with your makefile.

Now, for the test executable, the build commands are as follows:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o testmain main.o test.so
```

To run it, simply execute the `testmain` executable, but be sure the `test.so` library is on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

These are the files I used for test purposes:

test1.h:

```
int my_test_func1();
```

test1.cu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test1.h"

#define DSIZE 1024
#define DVAL 10
#define nTPB 256

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__global__ void my_kernel1(int *data){
  int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x *blockIdx.x);
  if (idx < DSIZE) data[idx] =+ DVAL;
}

int my_test_func1(){

  int *d_data, *h_data;
  h_data = (int *) malloc(DSIZE * sizeof(int));
  if (h_data == 0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); exit(1);}
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, DSIZE * sizeof(int));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++) h_data[i] = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, DSIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail");
  my_kernel1<<<((DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB), nTPB>>>(d_data);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel");
  cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, DSIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 2");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    if (h_data[i] != DVAL) {printf("Results check failed at offset %d, data was: %d, should be %d\n", i, h_data[i], DVAL); exit(1);}
  printf("Results check 1 passed!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

test2.h:

```
int my_test_func2();
```

test2.cu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test2.h"

#define DSIZE 1024
#define DVAL 20
#define nTPB 256

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__global__ void my_kernel2(int *data){
  int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x *blockIdx.x);
  if (idx < DSIZE) data[idx] =+ DVAL;
}

int my_test_func2(){

  int *d_data, *h_data;
  h_data = (int *) malloc(DSIZE * sizeof(int));
  if (h_data == 0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); exit(1);}
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, DSIZE * sizeof(int));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++) h_data[i] = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, DSIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail");
  my_kernel2<<<((DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB), nTPB>>>(d_data);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel");
  cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, DSIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 2");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    if (h_data[i] != DVAL) {printf("Results check failed at offset %d, data was: %d, should be %d\n", i, h_data[i], DVAL); exit(1);}
  printf("Results check 2 passed!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "test1.h"
#include "test2.h"

int main(){

  my_test_func1();
  my_test_func2();
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile according to the commands given, and run `./testmain` I get:

```
$ ./testmain
Results check 1 passed!
Results check 2 passed!
```

Note that if you prefer, you may generate a `libtest.so` instead of `test.so`, and then you may use a modified build sequence for the test executable:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o testmain main.o -L. -ltest
```

I don't believe it makes any difference, but it may be more familiar syntax.

I'm sure there is more than one way to accomplish this.  This is just an example.
You may wish to also review the relevant section of the [nvcc manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda) and also review the [examples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#examples).

**EDIT:** I tested this under cuda 5.5 RC, and the final application link step complained about not finding the cudart lib  (`warning: libcudart.so.5.5., needed by ./libtest.so, not found`).  However the following relatively simple modification (example Makefile) should work under either cuda 5.0 or cuda 5.5.

Makefile:

```
testmain : main.cpp  libtest.so
        g++ -c main.cpp
        g++ -o testmain  -L.  -ldl -Wl,-rpath,.   -ltest -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart main.o

libtest.so : link.o
        g++  -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so -o libtest.so    test1.o test2.o link.o  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64  -lcudart

link.o : test1.cu test2.cu   test1.h test2.h
        nvcc  -m64   -arch=sm_20 -dc  -Xcompiler '-fPIC'  test1.cu test2.cu
        nvcc  -m64   -arch=sm_20 -Xcompiler '-fPIC' -dlink test1.o test2.o -o link.o

clean :
        rm -f testmain test1.o test2.o link.o libtest.so main.o
```

Comment: The problem remains.  Following your example, everything compiles smoothly until the last step - in creating the test executable, at which point the `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft ...` error is thrown, as described before.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem could be. It seems to work perfectly for me. Are you following my steps and using my files exactly?  Are you using cuda 5.0 ?

Comment: @MatthewParks I have same problem with __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft ... , did you solve that

Answer (score 4):

The other answers did not work for me (maybe because I’m using cuda 10).
The solution that worked for me was compiling the cuda files as:

```
nvcc -dc -o cuda_file.o cuda_file.cu
```

Than compiling the c++ file as:

```
g++ -c -o cpp_file.o cpp_file.cpp
```

And finally linking all using nvcc:

```
nvcc -o my_prog cpp_file.o cuda_file.o -lcudart -lcuda -L<other stuff>
```

Don’t take this code literally. But the core of the solution to the error was using nvcc instead of g++ in the final linking step.

Comment: This fixed the issue in my case as well.