# nvlink, relocatable device code and static device libraries

Tags: cuda, linker, nvcc

While investigating some issues with relocatable device code, I stumbled upon something I don't quite understand.

This is a use case for what is pictured on [slide 6](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2012/presentations/gpu-object-linking.pdf#6). I used an [answer of Robert Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17287863/1043187) as a basis for a repro code. The idea is that we have some relocatable device code compiled into a static library (e.g. some math/toolbox library), and we want to use some functions of that precompiled library into another device library of our program:

```
libutil.a ---> libtest.so ---> test_pgm
```

Let's say that this external library contains the following function:

```
__device__ int my_square (int a);
```

`libutil.a` was for instance generated as follow (in another project):

```sh
nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -dc util.cu
nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -dlink util.o -o util_dlink.o
nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -lib util_dlink.o util.o -o libutil.a
```

Then, in our project, to generate `libtest.so`:

```sh
nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -dc test.cu
nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -dlink test.o libutil.a -o test_dlink.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so -o libtest.so test.o test_dlink.o libutil.a -L${CUDA_LIBDIR} -lcudart
```

But I get the following error when generating `test_dlink.o`:

```
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_Z9my_squarei' in 'test.o'
```

The linker does not find our dummy `my_square(int)` function. If we instead use (assuming we had access to `util.o`):

```
nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -dlink test.o util.o -o test_dlink.o
```

The linker succeeds and everything works fine after.

Investigating further:

```
$ nm -C libutil.a

util_dlink.o:
                 U atexit
                 U __cudaRegisterFatBinary
0000000000000015 T __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_0000106a_00000000_6_util_cpp1_ii_843d693d
  ...

util.o:
                 U __cudaInitModule
                 U __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_0000106a_00000000_6_util_cpp1_ii_843d693d
  ...
0000000000000015 T my_square(int)
  ...
```

The symbol is there in the archived `util.o`, but `nvlink` (called by `nvcc`) does not seem to find it. Why is that? According to the [official documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#libraries):

> The device linker has the ability to read the static host library
>   formats (.a on Linux and Mac, .lib on Windows).

We could of course extract the object file and link with it:

```sh
ar x libutil.a `ar t libutil.a | grep -v "dlink"`
nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -dlink test.o util.o -o test_dlink.o
```

But this does not feel like the expected solution... So what am I missing here? Another `nvcc` option that solves that? Is there an error when generating `libutil.a` and/or `libtest.so`?

Note that this was tested with CUDA 6.5 on Arch Linux.

### EDIT: fixed repro code with commented lines

#### Makefile

```
NVCC_FLAGS=-m64 -arch=sm_20 -Xcompiler '-fPIC'
CUDA_LIBDIR=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64

testmain : main.cpp libtest.so
    g++ -c main.cpp
    g++ -o testmain -L. -ldl -Wl,-rpath,. -ltest -L${CUDA_LIBDIR} -lcudart main.o

libutil.a : util.cu util.cuh
    nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -dc util.cu
    # ---> FOLLOWING LINES THAT WERE WRONG <---
    # nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -dlink util.o -o util_dlink.o
    # nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -lib util.o util_dlink.o -o libutil.a
    # INSTEAD:
    nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -lib util.o -o libutil.a
    # Assuming util is an external library, so util.o is not available
    rm util.o

libtest.so : test.cu test.h libutil.a util.cuh
    nvcc ${NVCC_FLAGS} -dc test.cu
    # Use NVCC for device linking + G++
    nvcc -v ${NVCC_FLAGS} -dlink test.o libutil.a -o test_dlink.o
    g++ -shared -o libtest.so test.o test_dlink.o libutil.a -L${CUDA_LIBDIR} -lcudart
    # Or let NVCC generate the shared library
    #nvcc -v ${NVCC_FLAGS} -shared -L. -lutil test.o -o libtest.so

clean :
    rm -f testmain *.o *.a *.so
```

#### test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
# define TEST_H

int my_test_func();

#endif //! TEST_H
```

#### test.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "test.h"
#include "util.cuh"

#define DSIZE 1024
#define DVAL 10
#define SQVAL 3
#define nTPB 256

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg)                             \
  do {                                                   \
    cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError();              \
    if (__err != cudaSuccess) {                          \
      fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
              msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err),            \
              __FILE__, __LINE__);                       \
      fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n");        \
      exit(1);                                           \
    }                                                    \
  } while (0)

__global__ void my_kernel(int *data){
  int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x *blockIdx.x);
  if (idx < DSIZE) data[idx] =+ DVAL + my_square (SQVAL);
}

int my_test_func()
{
  int *d_data, *h_data;
  h_data = (int *) malloc(DSIZE * sizeof(int));
  if (h_data == 0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); exit(1);}
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, DSIZE * sizeof(int));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++) h_data[i] = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, DSIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail");
  my_kernel<<<((DSIZE+nTPB-1)/nTPB), nTPB>>>(d_data);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel");
  cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, DSIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 2");
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    if (h_data[i] != DVAL + SQVAL*SQVAL)
    {
      printf("Results check failed at offset %d, data was: %d, should be %d\n",
             i, h_data[i], DVAL);
      exit(1);
    }
  printf("Results check passed!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

#### util.cuh

```
#ifndef UTIL_CUH
# define UTIL_CUH

__device__ int my_square (int a);

#endif //! UTIL_CUH
```

#### util.cu

```
#include "util.cuh"

__device__ int my_square (int a)
{
  return a * a;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
  my_test_func();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a straightforward name mangling issue. Note the linker is looking a mangled C++ symbol name and the object contains a C style unmangled name. There isn't enough information here to tell you how/what to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest putting a complete simple example in the question, just as I have done below.  External links to code are frowned on.  When they go stale, the question becomes less valuable.

Yes, you have an error in generating `libutil.a`  Creation of a static library with exposed device-linking is not the same as creation of a shared library with (by definition) no exposed device-linking.  Notice my mention of "CUDA-free wrapper" in the previous question you linked.  The example in this question has exposed device linking because `my_square` is in the library but is used by the code external to the library.

Review the [nvcc relocatable device code compiling examples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#examples) and you will find one that generates a device-linkable static library.  There is no device-link step in the static library *creation*.  The device-link step is done at the final executable creation (or in this case, at the creation of the so, i.e. the "CUDA boundary").  The "extra" device-link operation in static library creation is the proximal reason for the error you are observing.

Here's a fully worked example:

```
$ cat util.h

__device__ float my_square(float);

$ cat util.cu

__device__ float my_square(float val){ return val*val;}

$ cat test.h

float dbl_sq(float val);

$ cat test.cu
#include "util.h"

__global__ void my_dbl_sq(float *val){
  *val = 2*my_square(*val);
}

float dbl_sq(float val){
  float *d_val, h_val;
  cudaMalloc(&d_val, sizeof(float));
  h_val = val;
  cudaMemcpy(d_val, &h_val, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  my_dbl_sq<<<1,1>>>(d_val);
  cudaMemcpy(&h_val, d_val, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  return h_val;
}
$ cat main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(){

  printf("%f\n", dbl_sq(2.0f));
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -Xcompiler -fPIC -dc util.cu
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -Xcompiler -fPIC -lib util.o -o libutil.a
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -Xcompiler -fPIC -dc test.cu
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -shared -Xcompiler -fPIC -L. -lutil test.o -o libtest.so
$ g++ -o main main.cpp libtest.so
$ cuda-memcheck ./main
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
8.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

In this example, device-linking occurs automatically in the `nvcc` invocation that is used to create the .so library.  In my example here, I have already set my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to include my working directory.  Tested using CUDA 6.5 on CentOS 6.2  (Note that it is possible to perform multiple device-link operations during the creation of an executable, but these device-link operations must be within separate link domains, i.e. user-code or user-code entry points cannot be shared between the domains.  That is not the case here.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that device linking is useless when generating `libutil.a`, and that it needs to be done when linking with it. Simply removing that step solves it. After that, I do not need to rely on `nvcc` in that dummy example, but is `nvcc` doing something that justifies always using it for generating similar `libtest.so`? `nvcc` generates a call to `g++` with some extra linker options (`-lcudadevrt  -lcudart_static  -lrt -lpthread  -ldl`) that may not always be required. Note that I'm investigating a weird bug in a complex CMake-based CUDA build chain, so this actually matters.

Comment: We probably would need to drill into the specifics of your case (or mine).  In my case, I had trouble with the `libtest.so` created by `g++` (only) in that when I went to link with it later, I still had some unresolved symbols (not related to the ones in your question).  When I used `nvcc -shared` to create the so, these problems went away.  As you pointed out, the so could be created just fine if the static library were skipped.  So the combination of ordinary object + static library + device linking into a so meant I had to use `nvcc` for the so creation, but I did not research it further.

Comment: Is `-Xcompiler -fPIC` not redundant? That is, do we need it even when `-dc` or `-rdc` is used?

Comment: `-rdc` directs device code generation behavior.  `-Xcompiler` is a direction to the host compiler.  They are not redundant.