# CUDA Cooperative Groups : Linking error

Tags: cuda, linker-errors, nvcc, gpu-cooperative-groups

After reading about Cooperative Groups in CUDA 9, I've been trying synchronize at a grid level.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, a GTX 1060 and CUDA 9.1.

I altered my code as follows:

```
__global__ void ExplicitKernel_American(/* ... */) {
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    auto grid = cooperative_groups::this_grid();
    if (i < sizeS) {
        //...
        for (int j = 1; j < sizeT; ++j) {
            // ...
            grid.sync(); // __syncthreads();
        }
    }
}
```

And, as stated in the documentation, I call my kernel this way :

```
void* Explicit_Args[] = { &PDE_Grid, /* ... */, &sizeS, &sizeT };
cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel(
    (void*)ExplicitKernel_American, 
    dim3((sizeS + TPB - 1) / TPB), 
    dim3(TPB),  
    Explicit_Args
); // TPB being 256...
```

Unfortunately, I get linking errors as soon as I add the "grid" part in the kernel.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __fatbinwrap_38_cuda_device_runtime_compute_70_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I've set -rdc=true and sm_61 but cannot find why it is not working... Any ideas ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of a cooperative kernel launch (cooperative grid - CG) requires a Pascal or Volta GPU, and requires either Linux or a windows device operating in TCC mode.  If you test the `deviceProp.cooperativeLaunch` property  in the device properties structure, I think you will find that it is not supported on your GPU operating in WDDM mode.

It's good practice to test this property in your code, before attempting to use a cooperative grid launch.

The issue you are asking about is a compile/link issue, however.  For that, my recommendation is to study a CG (cooperative grid) sample code, such as  `6_Advanced/reductionMultiBlockCG`. For grid sync, its definitely a requirement to set `-rdc=true` (i.e. enable relocatable device code linking). Depending on how you set `-rdc=true`, it may not be applied to your project correctly.  The correct methodology is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260577/generating-relocatable-device-code-using-nvidia-nsight)

The proximal issue here appears to be that you are not correctly linking against the device runtime library,  e.g. `-lcudadevrt`

Comment: Hello, 

Indeed, the issue was that i was missing the -lcudadevrt. Is there a way to make this feature work ? I understood that it should work on Linux platforms. Also, why does this limitation exist ? Especially on WIndows, it has not been documented!

Comment: The ways to make it work I have already covered in my answer.  You cannot make it work currently under WDDM model.  The WDDM model imposes an OS-managed layer in between CUDA and device activities, which prevents the level of control necessary to make this feature work.  Regarding documentation, it is an oversight in the current docs, which I expect to be addressed in a future CUDA release.