# How can using cooperative groups feature of CUDA in windows

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, nvidia, gpu, gpu-cooperative-groups

My GPU is GeForce MX150, pascal architecture, CC. 6.1, CUDA 9.1, windows 10.
Although my GPU is pascal but cooperative groups doesn't work. I want to use it for inter-block synchronization.
I found my tcc mode doesn't active.
I also found that  doesn't active in wddm in windows.
How can using cooperative groups? 
How can activate tcc mode in windows? 
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't activate TCC on that GPU (it is not supported), and there is no way to use a cooperative launch under windows WDDM mode.

You'll either need to switch to linux or get another (pascal, volta, turing) GPU that can be placed in TCC mode on windows.

Also refer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777190/inter-block-synchronization-in-cuda) for instructions how to programmatically query for support of this feature.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681995/cuda-cooperative-groups-linking-error/49682279#49682279) may also be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think MX150 is a pascal architecture. I don't understand why my graphic card doesn't support.

Comment: Because GeForce GPUs don't support TCC mode.  That is by product design.  There is nothing you can do about it.