# CUDA nvcc building chain of libraries

Tags: cuda, dynamic-linking, nvcc

My goal is: `library2.so` is using `library1.so` and `mycode.o` is using (libs should be linked) `library2.so` (and maybe `library1.so`).

The source code is (one line header files are omitted):

library1.cu:

```
__device__ void func1_lib1(void){}
```

library2.cu:

```
#include "library1.h"
__global__ void func1_lib2(void)
{
    func1_lib1();
}
extern "C"
void func2_lib2(void)
{
    func1_lib2<<<1,1>>>();
}
```

mycode.c:

```
#include "library2.h"
int main(void)
{
    func2_lib2();
}
```

I'm building the shared libraries [according to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278932/cuda-shared-library-linking-undefined-reference-to-cudaregisterlinkedbinary) with Makefile

```
broken:
    rm -f *.o *.so
    nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dc library1.cu
    nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dlink -o cuda-lib1.o library1.o
    gcc  -shared -Wl,-soname,library1.so -o library1.so library1.o uda-lib1.o
    nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dc library2.cu
    nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dlink -o cuda-lib2.o library2.o -lrary1
    gcc  -shared -Wl,-soname,library2.so -o library2.so library2.o cuda-lib2.o
    gcc  -c mycode.c
    gcc  -o mycode -L. -lrary2 -lrary1 mycode.o

working:
    rm -f *.o *.so
    nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dc library1.cu
    nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dc library2.cu
    nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dlink -o cuda-lib.o library1.o library2.o
    gcc  -shared -Wl,-soname,library.so -o library.so library1.o library2.o cuda-lib.o
    gcc  -c -fPIC mycode.c                                                      
    gcc  -o mycode -L. -lrary  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart mycode.o
```

`make working` works without any problems. But it doesn't make a chain of libraries. `library1.cu` and `library2.cu` are in the same `.so` file.

`make broken` fails with

```
nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dlink -o cuda-lib2.o library2.o -lrary1
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_Z10func1_lib1v' in 'library2.o'
```

If I inspect `library1.so` by `nm` there is inside a target (T) `_Z10func1_lib1v`.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `make working` makes only one library not a chain of libraries.
Question is in the title: How to make a chain of libraries.

Comment: What I'm doing wrong if the compilation fails.

Comment: What is a "chain of libraries" supposed to mean?

Comment: Mycode depends on library2 and library2 depends on library1. First I'd like to compile library1. Than I'd like to compile library2 (without source code of library1; only with header files). The last step might be a compiling of mycode using compiled lib1 and lib2 and its header files without source code of these libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your "broken" approach, you are attempting to create a `library1.so` (a shared library) which contains only a `__device__` function:

```
__device__ void func1_lib1(void){}
```

Any other object that wished to use that `__device__` function must make use of [relocatable device code/separate compilation and linking](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda), which of course you are trying to do.

However, with respect to libraries, device linking [only supports functions contained in **static** libraries](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#libraries).  Note these statements from the `nvcc` manual:

> The device linker has the ability to read the **static** host library formats (.a on Linux and Mac OS X, .lib on Windows). It ignores any dynamic (.so or .dll) libraries.

and:

> Note that only **static** libraries are supported by the device linker.

So your general strategy won't work.   A possible workaround would be to place the library1.cu code in a static library:

```
rm -f *.o *.so
nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dc library1.cu
nvcc -arch=sm_30 --lib -o cuda-lib1.a library1.o
nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dc library2.cu
nvcc -arch=sm_30 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -dlink -o cuda-lib2.o library2.o cuda-lib1.a
gcc  -shared -Wl,-soname,library2.so -o library2.so -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart library2.o cuda-lib2.o cuda-lib1.a
gcc  -c mycode.c
gcc  -o mycode -L. -lrary2  mycode.o
```

Or else to create a sequence of `.so` libraries that don't require device linking across library boundaries, which is more-or-less demonstrated in your "working" case.