# How can I create and use a dynamic library ".so" from CUDA C++ and use it inside C# code under Linux environment (CentOS)?

Tags: c#, c++, linux, cuda, shared-libraries

I am trying to create a dynamic library **.so** using **CUDA C++** kernel to use it inside **C#** code under **Linux** environment (**CentOS**). I searched for a way yo do this, but unfortunately didn't find a complete clear solution for it. Some solutions only make partial part of it, like [creating C++ shared library on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496664/c-dynamic-shared-library-on-linux), or [creating chain of libraries in CUDA using nvcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897002/cuda-nvcc-building-chain-of-libraries), but there was no method for creating a dynamic library from **CUDA C++**. The using of **.so** created from **C++** seamed possible like in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072961/calling-unix-and-linuxshared-object-file-so-from-c-sharp).

Is there a way to create this dynamic library and use it successfully inside **C#** code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching multiple different solutions, and trying to collect and test the available possibilities, I finally reached to this simple method.
The original C++ library can be made using **gcc** in one step like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884126/build-so-file-from-c-file-using-gcc-command-line).

```
gcc -shared -o dll.so -fPIC dllmain.cpp
```

but make sure to add `extern "C"` before the required function(s) inside **.cpp** file, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" void func()
{
    // code
}
```

For **CUDA C++**, **nvcc** can be used in the same way similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423643/creating-dll-from-cuda-using-nvcc) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897002/cuda-nvcc-building-chain-of-libraries) combined. Make sure to use **.so** instead of **.dll** and use the proper device architecture, I used 60 here as I am using "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB".

```
nvcc -arch=sm_60 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -o dll.so --shared kernel.cu
```

The **.cu** file will be similar to this.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" void myfunc(int a, int b, ...);
__global__ void kernel(int a, int b, ...);

__global__ void kernel(int a, int b, ...)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    // kernel code
}

void myfunc(int a, int b, ...)
{
    // code
}
```

Now the dynamic library **.so** is created and can be used inside **C#** code like this.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Program
{
    [DllImport("dll.so")]
    static extern myfunc(int a, int b, ...);

    private void Method()
    {
        int a, b;
        // code
        myfunc(a, b, ...);
    }
}
```

The **C#** code then is compiled [using Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/).

```
mcs Program.cs
mono Program.exe
```

But it will probably be necessary to set the path of the used library like this.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/library/
```

This worked for a simple **CUDA C++** code, it will likely work for other ones, but some problems may arise depending on their complexity.

Comment: I recommend modifying your answer so that `myfunc` launches the CUDA kernel completing the full story.  Right now `kernel()` is unused and could be removed from the source.